# Nodejs glob multiple patterns

Tags: node.js, wildcard, glob

Is it possible to include multiple patterns in a single search string in glob for nodejs?
Like i need to find all files that have "*abc*.pdf" and "*xyz.pdf*".

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using [node-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) you can provide multiple patterns like this:

```
 "*(pattern1|pattern2|...)"
```

Which would translate in your example like:

```
 "*(abc.pdf|xyz.pdf)"
```

Full example (find all .html and .js files in current directory):

```
glob("*(*.js|*.html)", {}, function (err, files) {
   console.log(files)
})
```

Comment: `**/(*.tsx|*.ts)` doesn't seem to work, I had to do `**/*.ts*`

Answer (score 2):

For who want a glob options with recursive matching with multiple file extension. This will match all file within the `path` folder that has extension `.ts?x` and `.js?x`.

```
import * as glob from "glob";
// Synchronous operation
glob.sync(`path/**/*(*.ts|*.tsx|*.js|*.jsx)`, {...globOptions});
// Asynchronous operation
glob(`path/**/*(*.ts|*.tsx|*.js|*.jsx)`, {...globOptions}, () => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/217#issuecomment-139030154) you can use `{,,,,}` syntax for multiple matches:

```js
glob.sync('{abc.pdf,xyz.pdf}')
```

With wildcards:

```js
glob.sync('{*.js,*.html}')
```