# How to make the rollup CLI watch.include multiple files or directories?

Tags: command-line-interface, watch, rollup

I'm starting a rollup process with watching using:

```
npx rollup -c rollup.config.js --watch --watch.include=js/**
```

But now I want to add a second directory that I want to watch as well: `styles/**`

How chan I change the command so that *both* the `js` and `styles` directories are being watched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: this no longer seems to work with a newer version of rollup. Instead I now simply add

```
{
    watch: {
        include: ["js/**", "styles/**"]
    }
}
```

to the rollup config.

---

old answer:

If you are configuring your watcher from your `rollup.config.json` you could simply use an array for the [`watch.include` property](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#watchinclude). But on the CLI this is not an option.

You could, however, change the glob pattern in the command so that it contains multiple patterns (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455115/nodejs-glob-multiple-patterns)).

Then your command would become:

```
npx rollup -c rollup.config.js --watch --watch.include=*(js/**|styles/**)
```